# How does `super` interacts with a class's `__mro__` attribute in multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass, super

Today, I read the [official doc of super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).
In which it mentioned multiple inheritance will be decided by the `__mro__` attribute of a class.
So I did a bit experiment, but its result surprised me.

```
# CODE PART
class GrandFather(object):
    def p(self):
        print "I'm old."

class Father(GrandFather):
    def p(self):
        print "I'm male."

class Mother(object):
    def p(self):
        print "I'm female."

class Son(Father, Mother):
    def p(self):
        print "busy, busy, crwaling. "


 # EXPERIMENT PART
In [1]: Son.__mro__
Out[1]: (__main__.Son, __main__.Father, __main__.GrandFather, __main__.Mother, object)

In [2]: Father.__mro__
Out[2]: (__main__.Father, __main__.GrandFather, object)

In [3]: Mother.__mro__
Out[3]: (__main__.Mother, object)

In [4]: GrandFather.__mro__
Out[4]: (__main__.GrandFather, object)

In [5]: s = Son()

In [6]: super(Son, s).p()
I'm male.

In [7]: super(Father, s).p()
I'm old.

In [8]: super(Mother, s).p()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ce4d0d6ef62d> in <module>()
----> 1 super(Mother, s).p()

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'p'

In [9]: super(GrandFather, s).p()
I'm female.
```

Below is part of the official doc I mentioned above, it says:

```
super(type[, object-or-type])
Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type.   
This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.  
The search order is same as that used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.

The __mro__ attribute of the type lists the method resolution search order  
used by both getattr() and super().   
The attribute is dynamic and can change whenever the inheritance hierarchy is updated.

If the second argument is an object, isinstance(obj, type) must be true.
```

By combining this doc and the result of my experiment. The most confusing part is that when calling with `super(GrandFather, s).p()` it calls the `p()` of `Mother`, but `Mother` isn't in `GrandFather`'s `__mro__`, and it is on very inferior order of `Son`'s `__mro__`.

After a bit pondering. I got a plausible explanation which indicate the incompleteness or deficiency of the official doc:
That is when using with `super(type, instance)`, the `super` function will search from the `__mro__` attribute of the `class` from who your `instance` is build, but not the `__mro__` attribute of the `type` you passed to `super`, even if it satisfied the `isinstance(instance, type)` condition.

So what happened when you typed `super(Class, instance)` is:

1. Python check if `isinstance(instance, Class)` is True.
2. Python find the `__class__` attribute of `instance`,
   get the the `instance.__class__`'s `__mro__` attribute.
3. Python find the index of `Class` you passed to `super` in the `__mro__` tuple in step2.
4. Python add the index of step3 by 1, use it to get the corresponding class in `__mro__` tuple of step 2, and return the super delegate of this corresponding class.
5. If the index in step4 exceed length of `__mro__` of step2, the delegate of last class in `__mro__` of step2 is returned, which is the `object` class.

Is my understanding right?
If I'm wrong, what's the correct mechanism that `super` interacts with `type`'s `__mro__`?
If I'm right, how should I raise an issue for python official doc modification?
Because I think the current version about this item could be misleading.

---

PS: This test was done by `Python 2.7.6 within IPython 3.2.1`.

Comment: Great question, surprising behaviour!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `__mro__` of `Son`:

```
__main__.Son, __main__.Father, __main__.GrandFather, __main__.Mother, object
```

According to the doc:

> The `__mro__` attribute of the type lists the method resolution search order

So methods will be searched according to the order in the `__mro__` list, from left to right. Call of `super(type, instance)` will change the starting position to the type specified as the first argument of `super()` in the `__mro__` list of the class of the instance specified as the second argument (if the second argument passed to super is a instance):

`super(Son, s)`  will proxy to `__main__.Father`

`super(Father, s)`  will proxy to `__main__.GrandFather`

`super(GrandFather, s)`  will proxy to `__main__.Mother`

`super(Mother, s)` will proxy to `object`

The interesting part is why `__mro__` of `Son` is like it is. In other words why Mother is after GrandFather. This is because of how the linearization is working in python:

> the linearization of C is the sum of C plus the merge of the linearizations of  the parents and the list of the parents.

See the examples in the [documentation](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) you mentioned, it explains a very similar case.

So that final result is actually correct: `super(GrandFather, s).p()` should be `I'm female.`

Comment: "Call of super(type, instance) will change the starting position to the type specified as the first argument of super()" - This really helped me understand the results, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I understood that after pondering. Then I updated my question. But the the issue is, here the doc is ambiguous. Let's see the usage example of super in doc: `super(type[, object-or-type])`,  Two names of type here, right? No visual distinction at all. Then let's see the `__mro__` description in doc: `The __mro__ attribute of the type lists the method resolution search order used by both getattr() and super(). ` Since I can pass both object/instance and type to `super`. Without specification, shouldn't a learner naturally think that the first type is what the doc statement refers to?

Comment: Plus, in its only example under `super`, its using the `super(type, object)` statement to call the super. How should a learner naturally understood here we are using the object's type's `__mro__` with the current version doc's description?

Comment: @Mariusz Jamro, A reminder for the statement in your answer `in the __mro__ list of the instance specified as the second argument`. The instance doesn't have `__mro__` attribute, the original class which generate this instance has `__mro__` attribute. So in a more accurate way, the statement should be `in the __mro__ list of the original class where the instance generates from (if the second argument passed to super is a instance)`

Answer (score 0):

From chapt 32 of [learning python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do):

> each super call selects the method from a next class following it in the MRO ordering of the class of the self subject of a method call.

so for `super(cls, instance)`(`isinstance(instance, cls)` must be `True`), the method is selected from the next class in `instance.__class__.__mro__` starting from `instance.__class__`.

for `super(cls0, cls1)`(`issubclass(cls1, cls0)` must be `True`), the method is selected from next class in `cls1.__mro__` starting from `cls0`

in both cases, if the method is not implemented by the next class in the MRO chain, the search will skip ahead until it finds a class with the method defined.